# Unable to declare an extension method to the App (ionic-angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, typescript2.0

In my `/ext/app-entension.ts` ("typescript": "^2.4.2") I declare an extension function to the `App` (ionic-angular) class:

```
// **error #1** from the list below
import { NavController, App } from "ionic-angular"; 

interface App {
    getMyCoolNav(): NavController;
}

// **error #2** from the list below
App.prototype.getMyCoolNav = function(this: App): NavController {
    // logic to define suitable nav combining the following calls
    // this.getRootNavs && this.getActiveNavs
    // **error #3** from the list below
}
```

And the in my pages I can just import this extension and use it without any issue:

```
import { NavController, App } from "ionic-angular";
import '../ext/app-extensions'

// **error #4** from the list below
this.app.getMyCoolNav().push(MyCoolPage);
```

It works fine in runtime while VS Code / Typescript is giving me hard time with all kind of errors:

1. import: [ts] Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'App'.
2. prototype assignment: [ts] Property 'getMyCoolNav' does not exist on type 'App'.
3. `this` usage in prototype: [ts] Property 'getRootNavs' does not exist on type 'App'.
4. in my pages: [ts] Property 'getMyCoolNav' does not exist on type 'App'.

What could be wrong with my extension method registration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Typescript's declaration merging with an interface imported from a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637028/how-can-i-use-typescripts-declaration-merging-with-an-interface-imported-from-a)

Answer (score 0):

You need to augment the module with the interface to tell the compiler about the new interface. e.g.

File test.ts

```
export class Test {
    getSomething(): string {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

File testExtensions.ts

```
import { Test } from "./test";

declare module "./test" {
    interface Test {
        getSomethingElse(): string;
    }
}

Test.prototype.getSomethingElse = function(): string {
    return "somethingElse";
}
```

This does tell the compiler about the interface and you should be able to extend the prototype as needed. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html, search for "Module Augmentation"