# interface merge with import & local not working?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Examples of interface merging shown it is possible to merge interface in *single file*.
But I cannot merge interfaces when they are in different files.

Note that I'm not augmenting any modules, no modules, just interface.

/types/index.d.ts

```
export interface A { baseline: string }
```

/someFile.ts

```
import {A} from './types/index'; // <-- Error "Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'A'"
import {FancyInterface} from './SomeClass'

interface A {
  someAdditionalFlavor: FancyInterface
}
export default class ABC implements A {}
```

I am intended to use the same interface name here, because they are literally the same interface, 
but since I am sharing the base interface with other modules, which I can't add FancyInstance there.

Comment: You can provide an alias to the importation. `import { A as ImportedA } from '...';`

Comment: When you say "I'm not augmenting any modules, no modules, just interfaces", you are making a false statement. Interfaces declared in a module are scoped to that module just like every other declaration there in. It is not possible to merge interface declarations across modules. Augmentation is your only option.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Hi, I come from a Node.js background, have not used TypeScript. What module do you mean? Do Modules mean files? So different files are considered different modules, is that what you're saying?

Comment: @VRoxa Good workaround!

Comment: In typescript, a file is considered a module if it contains one or more imports or exports.

Comment: I think question is answered over here a in a bit more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637028/how-can-i-use-typescripts-declaration-merging-with-an-interface-imported-from-a . The answer is basically that you can't merge an imported interface with a local one because they are defined in different scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To record the answer and make easier to see it for others in the future.

You can provide an alias when importing, like so

```
import { A as ImportedA } from './types/index';
import { FancyInterface } from './SomeClass'

interface A {
  someAdditionalFlavor: FancyInterface
}

// Then use distinct A or ImportedA
```

Comment: I am confused. OP wanted to merge two interfaces, but what's being merged here? I guess we'd need a `declare global { ... }` somewhere.