# Specifying the type for Threejs Object3D.userData in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, three.js, extend, user-data, .d.ts

In Three.js there is a field on `Object3D` class called userData, which in the type declaration file `node_modules/three/src/core/Object3D.d.ts` is defined as

```
/**
 * Base class for scene graph objects
 */
export class Object3D extends EventDispatcher {

[...]

    /**
     * An object that can be used to store custom data about the Object3d. It should not hold references to functions as these will not be cloned.
     * @default {}
     */
    userData: { [key: string]: any };

[...]

}
```

I wanted to more strongly type the userData, so I created a module type declaration `src/typings/three.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'three' {
  export class Object3D {
    userData: MyType1 | MyType2;
  }
}

type MyType1 = {
  type: 'type1';
  radius: number;
};
type MyType2 = {
  type: 'type2';
  name: string;
};
```

This, while it did overwrite the `userData` property, it instead of merging, overwrote all type declarations in the `three` module, making the change more damaging than useful (note the lack of other properties).
[image: Missing type declarations in vscode]

Is there a way to merge the type declarations in a way that *only* `userData` is overwritten and not entire module?

Answer (score 4):

In typescript jargon, what you're trying to do is "declaration merging" combined with "module augmentation" (see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)). There are a few problems with your sample so far, most of which is fixable, one of which is not (i.e. you've hit a limitation of the language).

I'm going to first explain these problems and (partial) solutions, and then suggest an alternative approach that will work completely.

1. When you want to augment a class definition through module augmentation, your augmentation must be in the form of an un-exported interface, not an exported class definition. So instead of `export class Object3D` you must write `interface Object3D`. (Not the most intuitive thing, I know - but [the docs state](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#disallowed-merges) "Not all merges are allowed in TypeScript. Currently, classes can not merge with other classes or with variables.")
2. You must match the signature of the class you are trying to augment *exactly*, including generic parameters and `extends` statements. So instead of...

   ```
   interface Object3D {
   ```

   ...you'd need to write...

   ```
   interface Object3D<E extends BaseEvent> extends EventDispatcher<E> {
   ```

   (hat tip to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52637469/4739687) for pointing out this poorly-documented "gotcha")
3. The particular way that `@types/three` is written, it's not just one big file with "export class Object3D..." type statements at the top-level. Instead, the root file of `@types/three` has this statement:

   ```
   export * from './src/Three';
   ```

   In turn, `src/Three` had (among other things) this statement:

   ```
   export * from './core/Object3D';
   ```

   And the `src/core/Object3D` finally has the core class definition:

   ```
   export class Object3D<E extends BaseEvent = Event> extends EventDispatcher<E> {
   ```

   I've found through experimentation (although I can't find a clear explanation as to why) that these intermediate `export *` statements get in the way of your module augmentation code actually matching up with the thing it's trying to affect (e.g. the `Object3D` class definition in `@types/three/src/core/Object3D`). To get around this, your `declare module` statement must target that file specifically, not the re-exported version of it.

So putting all this together, this will (*almost*) work:

```
import { BaseEvent, EventDispatcher } from "three";

declare module "three/src/core/Object3D" {
  interface Object3D<E extends BaseEvent> extends EventDispatcher<E> {
    // This works fine...
    somethingElse: string;
    // However, this does not (see below)
    // Typescript will throw this error: 
    // Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'userData' must be of type '{ [key: string]: any; }'
    userData: MyType1 | MyType2;
  }
}
```

This final problem is a limitation of the language - declaration merging cannot *change* the type of an existing property on the original class definition (even if the new type is technically a sub-type of the original one). It can only add *new* properties to the class.

***An Alternative Approach That Does Work***

Instead of using declaration *merging*, you can make a new class declaration that extends the original, and override the type there:

```
declare module "three" {
  import { BaseEvent } from "three/src/core/EventDispatcher";
  import { Object3D as Object3DOriginal } from "three/src/core/Object3D";
  export * from "three/src/Three";
  export class Object3D<E extends BaseEvent = Event> extends Object3DOriginal<
    E
  > {
    userData: MyType1 | MyType2;
  }
}
```

Check out [this codesandbox for a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-module-augmentation-2qy1pi?file=/src/types.d.ts).

Comment: This solution works in simple cases, but doesn't work in most. For example, `getObjectByName` still returns the original Object3D type, not the overridden type. See https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-module-augmentation-forked-47yev7